# Why does this naming of nodes via a foreach loop result in an error message even though it seems that the naming works partially?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, programming

**Question.**

Why does

```
\documentclass{amsart}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \index in {0,1,2,3}{
  \node (v\index) at (\index cm, \index cm)[]{$v_{\index}$};
    %\draw (v0)--(v1);    
  \draw (v0)--($(v0)+(1 cm,0 cm)$);
 }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

compile, while

```
\documentclass{amsart}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}


\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \index in {0,1,2,3}{
  \node (v\index) at (\index cm, \index cm)[]{$v_{\index}$};
  \draw (v0)--(v1);    
  %\draw (v0)--($(v0)+(1 cm,0 cm)$);
  }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

results in an error message

> No shape named v1 is known.

?

**Remark.**

- I would also appreciate advice, if the present one is not recommendable, about how to make the *name of a node depend on a loop variable*.
- I simply do not see a reason for the above error message, neither from rereading the code, nor the manual, nor from reading discussions about naming nodes in TikZ---the node name seems to have been defined. I hope that this is not a bug, rather, that I am overlooking something easily fixed.

Comment: You are using `v1` without creating it before, when the foreach index is = 0

Comment: @CarLaTeX: many thanks. Of course, you are right. This is embarassing for me. Whether you believe it or not, the reason for having asked it that way is this: the real motivation is a larger code, wherein I use the \draw (v0)--(v1); **outside** the loop parentheses, and **still** get an error. However, this error might be due to some additional complexities. I then tried to comply with the 'give a minimal nonworking example' guideline, and ended up producing this triviality. I am afraid I cannot easily describe the error I am really interested in, without posting a huge code. Many thanks again.

Comment: Don't worry, the important thing is that you've found a solution :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The reason for the error message is already explained in CarLaTeX's [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/388427/why-does-this-naming-of-nodes-via-a-foreach-loop-result-in-an-error-message-even#comment963423_388427).

I assume, you want to connect the nodes with lines. Then, the previous node can be remembered by option `remember`. The `\if` construct excludes the first loop, when there is only just one node defined yet.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \index [remember=\index as \lastindex] in {0,1,2,3}{
  \node (v\index) at (\index cm, \index cm)[]{$v_{\index}$};
  \ifnum\index>0
    \draw (v\lastindex) -- (v\index);
  \fi
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

A variant without `\ifnum`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}

\foreach \index in {0, 1, 2, 3} {
  \node (v\index) at (\index cm, \index cm)[]{$v_{\index}$};
}
\draw
  \foreach \index [remember=\index as \lastindex (initially 0)] in {1, 2, 3} {
    (v\lastindex) -- (v\index)
  }
;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

A possible solution is to define the first node out of the cicle:

```
\documentclass{amsart}   
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    \node (v0) {$v_0$};
    \foreach[evaluate=\index as \indexj using int(\index+1)] \index in {0,1,2}{
        \node (v\indexj) at (\indexj cm, \indexj cm)[]{$v_{\indexj}$};
        \draw (v\index)--(v\indexj);    
    }
    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]